# finding users IP Address and MAC address from web browser

Tags: javascript, asp.net, web

Is it possible to find out the clients IP and possibly MAC address from non IE browsers (i.e. without using ActiveX)? If so, how?

Comment: You'll be lucky getting your hands on the MAC address matey! DmitryK's response is how I'd have envisaged you getting your hands on the IP address, tho'.

Comment: Why do you need the MAC address? it's meaningless to the server unless you're on the same network (at which point you could do an ARP request based on the IP address)

Comment: I can get (and have) gotten hold of the MAC address in IE. Didn't think it would be possible without ActiveX though.

Comment: @Rowland - It's for making sure one user within a company doesn't hand his username and password to everyone and their dog and let them all use it.

Comment: @Ben You might need to solve that "some other way", as they may be using a multi-homed device, or have a genuine need to "pop up" somewhere else. Bear in mind that the server can also only see the IP address of the client connected to it, which *might* be a proxy server (which *might* lie to you). You could use some sort of cookies, and detect multiple instances of the same login details with differing cookies. Whilst not infallible, it may be enough to put off casual abusers (really, the only true solution is "lawyers")

Comment: Add a "Logged in as Bob (not Bob?)" with the latter part being a link - and if clicked pop up a message on the legality of using Bob's account - suggesting that their PUG4-ID has been tracked.  :)

Answer (score 1):

You can get client's IP address on the web server via server variables. Why don't you just embed that info in the page that is sent back to the client? Then client will be able to read from the page.